# Why does my query sends no results but I have data in my db?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am learning to build APIs using .NET6 and EF. But I have a strange result when executing my GetAll repository method.

This is what I have :

```
var pizzas = this.dbContext.Pizzas
                 .Include(pizza => pizza.Sauce)
                 .Include(pizza => pizza.Extras)
                 .AsNoTracking()
                 .AsEnumerable();

return pizzas;
```

The thing is, when I execute my method in debug mode, I have "Enumeration yielded no results" in my pizzas var. But I do have data in my database. I checked and re-checked, but I do have a pizza in my Pizza table. So, I am a bit confused about why is it sending me an empty enumeration taking in consideration I should have a result ? In addition to that, I do not have conditions in my call, so do you have any idea about what do I need to change ?

Thanks,

Comment: Likely the database the application is using is not the same instance as the database you are looking at. Could be a local db, or dbcontext is in memory, or the server is different, or the instance is named, or something else.

Comment: What do you see when you debug and look at the dbContext and dbContext.Pizzas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most common issue is what Igor mentioned. Check the connection string at runtime adding

```
var connectionString = dbContext.Database.GetConnection().ConnectionString;
```

Then compare that to where you are checking. Often the problem happens if someone checks in a change to the connection string (creating a new local database or pointing at a different DB than you expect) or you've move the DbContext to a separate assembly and updated config files in that assembly but the main application's config still points at an old/invalid location resulting in it going to an old DB or newly created one.